# Divider into ng-repeat for random number of iterations

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need to create an `ng-repeat` iteration with divider in it. The problem is that I have to add divider after every two, three or four elements randomly. I started with this code:

```
<li repeat-start="person in persons track by $index">
  <p>{{ person.name }}</p>
</li>

<li ng-repeat-end ng-if="($index + 1) % 2 === 0">
  <p>--divider--</p>
</li>
```

It works great when I specify the exact value of 2 inside `ng-if`. It shows me result like that.

- Person 1
- Person 2
- --divider--
- Person 3
- Person 4
- --divider--
- Person 5
- etc...

But how to specify this coefficient dynamically? I added a function to genereate a random number among 2, 3 and 4.

```
  $scope.getNumber = function() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (3) + 2);
  }
```

But when I try to change hardcoded value I cannot see the desirable result. None of these solutions works. Neigher with simple function call.

```
ng-if="($index + 1) % getNumber() === 0"
```

nor with `ng-init` variations.

```
<li repeat-start="person in persons track by $index" ng-init="coeff = getNumber()">
  <p>{{ person.name }}</p>
</li>

<li ng-repeat-end ng-if="($index + 1) % coeff === 0">
  <p>--divider--</p>
</li>
```

How to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was with *Infinite $digest Loop*, which was caused by fact, that `getNumber` function returns random results, so AngularJS can't stabilize itself. To calculate `getNumber` only once for each `ng-repeat` iteration, you can use `ng-init` directive, as you already did (may be your code doesn't work due to typo: `repeat-start` instead of `ng-repeat-start`):

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.persons = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < 20; i++)
      $scope.persons.push({name:'Person ' + i});
      
    $scope.getNumber = function() {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * 3 + 2);
    }
}])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<ul ng-app='app' ng-controller='ctrl'>
  <li ng-init='temp = getNumber()' ng-repeat-start="person in persons">
    <p>{{person.name}}</p>
  </li>
  <li ng-repeat-end ng-if="($index + 1) % temp === 0">
    <p>--divider--</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Another solution is to "cache" results of `getNumber` function, for example at `person` entity:

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.persons = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < 20; i++)
      $scope.persons.push({name:'Person ' + i});
            
    $scope.getNumber = function(person) {      
      return person.temp || (person.temp = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3 + 2));
    }
}])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<ul ng-app='app' ng-controller='ctrl'>
  <li ng-repeat-start="person in persons">
    <p>{{person.name}}</p>
  </li>
  <li ng-repeat-end ng-if="($index + 1) % getNumber(person) === 0">
    <p>--divider--</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: that's the perfect answer for getting a random value from an array ... in an ng-repeat without getting error ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this (some refactorings):

```
<li repeat-start="person in persons track by $index">
  <p>{{ person.name }}</p>
  <p ng-if="putDividerHere($index)">--divider--</p>
</li>

$scope.putDividerHere(index) {
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (3) + 2);
    return ((index + 1) % randomNumber) === 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A small change needed. Call a function in your `ng-if` that cals the `getNumber` function and returns the condition *true/false*

HTML:

```
<li ng-repeat-end ng-if="isShowDivider($index+1)">
  <p>--divider--</p>
</li>
```

JS:

```
$scope.isShowDivider = function (index) {
  if (index % $scope.getNumber() !== 0) 
     return false;
  return true;
}

$scope.getNumber = function() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (3) + 2);
}
```

**Edit** for the `iterations reached. Aborting` error.

```
<li ng-repeat="person in persons track by $index">
  <p>{{person.name}}</p>
  <p ng-if="isShowDivider($index+1)">--divider--</p>
</li>
```

Comment: I always get the error "iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [[{"msg":"isShowDivider($index + 1)","newVal":true,"oldVal":false}"

Comment: The same issue remains. Maybe its something specific in my app.